# Continuity of $f \mapsto \int_0^1 \lvert y - \langle y, f(t) \rangle f(t) \rvert^2 \ dt$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Fix $y \in \mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ (the $2$-sphere), I want to prove that the function defined by
>
> $$E: C^0([0,1];\mathbb{S}^2) \to \mathbb{R}, f \mapsto \int_0^1 \lvert y - \langle y, f(t) \rangle f(t) \rvert^2 \ dt $$
>
> is continuous.

I've tried the following: For $f, g \in C^0(I;\mathbb{S}^2)$, I can use the binomial formula to obtain:

\begin{align*} \lvert E(f) - E(g) \rvert &\leq \int_0^1 \bigl\lvert \lvert y - \langle y, f(t) \rangle f(t) \rvert^2 - \lvert y - \langle y, g(t) \rangle g(t) \rvert^2 \bigr\rvert \ dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \bigl\lvert \lvert y - \langle y, f(t) \rangle f(t) \rvert + \lvert y - \langle y, g(t) \rangle g(t) \rvert \bigr\rvert \ \\
& \ \ \ \cdot \bigl\lvert \lvert y - \langle y, f(t) \rangle f(t) \rvert - \lvert y - \langle y, g(t) \rangle g(t) \rvert \bigr\rvert \ dt = (*)
\end{align*}

Using that $f,g$ are $C^0(I;\mathbb{S}^2)$ and a triangle inequality for the second factor, we obtain for a constant $C = C(f,g)$ that
\begin{align*}
(*) &= C \int_0^1 \lvert \langle y, f(t) \rangle f(t) - \langle y, g(t) \rangle g(t) \rvert \ dt
\end{align*}

I know, I can choose $f,g$ close to one another in $C^0$, but I'm kinda dazzled by the scalar product which i cannot factor out to single out $f - g$.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\langle y , f(t) \rangle f(t)-\langle y , g(t) \rangle g(t)$$ $$=\langle y , [f(t)-g(t)] \rangle f(t)+\langle y , g(t) \rangle [f(t)-g(t)]$$.

Use Cauchy - Schwarz inequality for the first term.